# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null. Overlapping JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using a onclick function on my responsive menu.
But now I made an inlog page which uses the same head and footer include.
The responsive menu is not placed on my loginpage and because of that the code for the responsive menu gives me the error.

```
let menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
menuBtn.onclick = () => {
    let mainnav = document.querySelector(".mainnav");
    mainnav.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

This code runs perfectly if the menu button is present on the page.
But since the loginpage does not. It gives me an error and it seems that running into a error makes it not run the other parts of my JavaScript.

Can this part of the JavaScript code be ignored when the button is not present on the page?

Comment: `if (menuBtn) menuBtn.onlick...`. Or put this code in a separate JS file / block which is only loaded if the menu is loaded. P.S. Prefer addEventListener over onlick etc.

Comment: He ADyson. If you make it into an answer i can give you your credit.

Comment: Done, see below - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply test whether `menuBtn` is defined and populated before you try to use it:

```
if (menuBtn) menuBtn.onlick //...etc
```

Or you could put this code in a separate JS file / block which is only loaded if the menu is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The error can be avoided by checking if the variable `menuBtn` is not `null` before trying to set the `onclick` property.

```
let menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menuBtn");
if (menuBtn !== null) {
  menuBtn.onclick = () => {
    let mainnav = document.querySelector(".mainnav");
    mainnav.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```